# searching all documents in sharepoint

Tags: powershell, query

If I want to search all through my sharepoint site for all documents any place in the site.
Would it just be

```
Get-SPSite mysite |
Select -ExpandProperty allwebs |
Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
Select -ExpandProperty Items
```